# Search in the deepest layer of a nested array of objects, return the whole tree of the found object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion, search

JSON: https://api.jsonserve.com/SiEw5B

In this example the data has 3 layers, but it could be more

So I can do something like this to find the actual object

```
function findNode (id, array) {
    for (const node of array) {
    if(node.id===id)return node;    
    if (node.children) {
         const child = findNode(id, node.children);
            if(child) return child
                 
      }
    }
  }
```

But its not what I want, since I want the whole tree to be returned for the found object

So I had an idea to create a temporary array, recursively adding all of them to it, and only keep the ones that had the target object hidden in them

But the problem is that no matter how I tried to resolve it, I ended up for 4 more for loops, cause of all the mapping, filtering etc..

Is there a simple way to fix this

So for the end result if searching for "test-child-1" Id like

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'test-parent',
    children: [
        {
            id: '1a',
            name: 'test',
            children: [
                {
                    id: '1a1',
                    name: 'test-child-1',
                    children: null,
                }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or only by doing a bunch of array.push, filtering, mapping, etc.. and taking up a lot of memory etc?

Comment: Take a look at the npm package object-scan and the "parents" callback arg. That should be exactly what you want! (disclaimer I'm the author of object-scan)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fairly simple solution:

(**Fixed for problem from comments**)

```js
const findDeep = (pred) => (xs) => {
  for (let x of xs) {
    if (pred (x)) {return [x]}
    const c = findDeep(pred) (x.children || [])
    if (c) return [{...x, children: c}]
  }
}

const findDeepById = (target) => findDeep (x => x .id == target)

const data = [{"id":"1","name":"test-parent","children":[{"id":"1a","name":"test","children":[{"id":"1a1","name":"test-child-1","children":null},{"id":"1a2","name":"test-child-2","children":null},{"id":"1a3","name":"test-child-3","children":null}]},{"id":"1b","name":"test2","children":[{"id":"1b1","name":"test2-child-1","children":null}]}]},{"id":"2","name":"test-2-parent","children":[{"id":"2a","name":"test-2","children":[{"id":"2a1","name":"test-2-child-1","children":null}]}]}]

console .log (findDeepById ('1a1') (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**Old version:**

```js
const findDeep = (pred) => (xs) => {
  for (let x of xs) {
    if (pred (x)) {return [x]}
    const c = findDeep(pred) (x.children || [])
    if (c) return [{...x, children: [c]}]
  }
}

const findDeepById = (target) => findDeep (x => x .id == target)

const data = [{"id":"1","name":"test-parent","children":[{"id":"1a","name":"test","children":[{"id":"1a1","name":"test-child-1","children":null},{"id":"1a2","name":"test-child-2","children":null},{"id":"1a3","name":"test-child-3","children":null}]},{"id":"1b","name":"test2","children":[{"id":"1b1","name":"test2-child-1","children":null}]}]},{"id":"2","name":"test-2-parent","children":[{"id":"2a","name":"test-2","children":[{"id":"2a1","name":"test-2-child-1","children":null}]}]}]

console .log (findDeepById ('1a1') (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`findDeep` is generic, using an arbitrary predicate.  We create `findDeepById` as a function that takes a `target` and passes to `findDeep` a function that tests whether an object has a matching `id`.  We then call this on our data.

The main function should be pretty obvious.  We loop over the items in the array supplied.  If our current test item matches the predicate, we wrap it in an array and return it.  Otherwise, we recur on our item's children.  If we find a result there, we wrap the current object with a new `children` array containing that result.  If we get all the way through, we will not return anything.

This is not my usual style.  I know I've done similar problems before using pure expressions, not statements, but I seem to have mislaid them, and my brain isn't working well enough to figure it out now.

As to this:

> Is there a simple way to do this, or only by doing a bunch of array.push, filtering, mapping, etc.. and taking up a lot of memory etc?

first of all, why do you think those operations are memory-intensive?  This solution should be fine.  There are two local variables, and we only build up the output object we actually need to return.  If recursion depth is a problem, you likely need to reconsider your input data.

Comment: Thank you ,its very elegant and works great. I get you points, my code was extremely long and messy, didnt want to post that here
This is cool, however  it adds an extra parentheses in the children key "  "children": [
      [
        {" , Im gonna try to fix this. hopefully I'll manage, thanks anyway

Comment: Oops.  Fixed in the version above.

Comment: Thanks Scott I figured out in the meanwhile, truly cool algorithm you got up there, gonna have to study it before I fully get it. Next feature I want is so it can list multiple items (with parents) instead of just one so instead of a find it would be more like a filterDeep. Anyway I think thats on me now : D